# ASP.NET MVC 4 Deferred query execution not retrieving data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, deferred-execution

I am new in ASP.NET MVC 4. In my project I am using **Code First** technique in of EF. I want to retrieve some data from database and I used following code for this :

```
    List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var lm = from m in db.BOs //fetch data from database
             select m;
    foreach (var temp in lm)
    {
        ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.Name, Value = temp.Id.ToString() });
    }
```

But when execution pointer move inside `foreach` it immediately come back out of the loop showing `return ls` value `Count = 0`. Code does not giving me any error while running that's why I am not getting where is going wrong.

**UPDATE:** I found something new this problem. When I kept mouse pointer over `var lm`; it shows me query and in query table name in `FROM` clause is not that one in my SQL database. My SQL table name is `BO` and in query it is taking `BOes`. I don't know from where this name is coming. So How I overcome this??

Comment: Check your EF mappings and see what the table map to your entity BOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following code inside DbContext class :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

The modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove statement in the OnModelCreating method prevents table names from being pluralized. If you didn't do this, the generated tables would be named Students, Courses, and Enrollments. Instead, the table names will be Student, Course, and Enrollment. Developers disagree about whether table names should be pluralized or not. This tutorial uses the singular form, but the important point is that you can select whichever form you prefer by including or omitting this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

decorate your `BO` class with `Table("BO")` to specify the table name (attribute is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace)

```
[Table("BO")]
public partial class BO
{
    ...
```